# Whats the best way to load Object Oriented JS properties dependent on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have and external JS scripts file with all my objects in that runs once the document is ready something like this...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var Main = {
        run: function () {
             myFunction.setup();
        }
    }

    var myFunction = {
        setup: function() {
            //Do some stuff here
        } 
    }

    Main.run();
});
```

I want to be able to run myFunction.setup() only if im on a certain page though otherwise I get errors if that method is looking for elements on the page that don't exist e.g a slideshow, menus etc.

At the moment I have got round this by checking if the element exists with .length and if it does then running the rest of the method but I was wondering if there was a nicer way? Maybe like if it was possible to send variables to the scripts file when it loads based on the page im on so it knows what to methods run?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Giles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul Irish has a great way of doing exactly this, using ID and classes from the body tag to execute certain blocks of code:

http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/

Comment: Thanks Mathletics, I was doing exactly this on another site but wasn't sure it was correct, seeing that Mr Irish is doing the same thing is rewarding and the vidget article really seems a nice way of doing it!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing might help:

**Page specific**

```
var page_config = {
    setup_allowed: true
    // ... more config
};
```

**Generic**

```
var Main,
    myFunction;

(function ($, _config) {
    myFunction = (function () {
        var _public = {};
        if (_config.setup_allowed === true) {
            _public.setup = function () {

            };
        }
        return _public;
    })();

    Main = (function () {
        var _public = {};
        if (typeof myFunction.setup !== "undefined") {
            _public.run = function () {
                myFunction.setup();
            };
            // Run it as we had Main.run() before
            _public.run();
        }
        return _public;
    })();

})(jQuery, page_config);
```

This way `Main.run()` and `myFunction.setup()` are only available if specified in `page_config`.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jakeclarkson/RGjQ8/) you can have a play with. This may be a bit verbose for your particular requirement but hopefully it'll help in some way :-)

Comment: Thanks for the example Jake, slightly more complex than I can get my head round at the moment, is page_config a global variable set on the actual page I presume?

Comment: Sorry, it looked good in my head but got a bit more complex as I wrote it down :-) Yep that `page_config` is just a global variable in each of your pages; the rest of it would just be contained in one JS file imported on each page. The code makes use of the [module design pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) to conditionally include `function`s only if specified in `page_config`.

Comment: Thanks Jake, yep it sounds good in theory, theres something about having javascript on the page though that im not keen on, weird i know ha! Anyway I went with the other approach of putting data attributes on the body tag output via the php which is working nicely. I might give this approach a go on my next project though, thanks again for your time.